# Unable to check-in the inhertied XSD file in visual studio 2015 TFS due to the length error?

Tags: biztalk

I have a  Biztalk Service which calls other services. I have  generated the XSD file from the WSDL file But unable to check-in the  inhertied 
XSD file in TFS due to the length.
 
I have manually map that particular solution to the minimum path in my local but still the schema name is too big.
If i rename the XSD which is dependent on other XSD which generates the error. 
so is there any approch to solve this(Renaming of xsd giving error) ?

Answer (score 2):

You mean path length?

Sure, it's very easy to just shorten the paths and or file names.

All you need to do is also update the Include/Import paths in the including .xsd.  To do this, you will have to edit the .xsd in the Xml Editor, the Schema Editor has trouble with this.